# Azure IOT hub message fails if larger than 5000 bytes

Tags: esp32, azure-iot-sdk

I have been testing the SDK with code based on the Azure-ESP-Starter code.
When I try to send a larger message body the message fails. I am using an ESP32 Wroom and the SDK installed in VScode.
Message length of 5438 transmits ok, but 5458 fails.
I was looking for a reason and noticed that in the TCP settings, the default send buffer size = 5744
If I change this to 15744 I can send a 10,000 byte message.
The SDK seems to be failing when trying to fragment & send larger messages.
At first I thought it may have something to do with the TLS maximum outgoing fragment length setting (default 4096), but increasing this did not resolve the problem. The TCP buffer setting does allow larger messages.
I thought that Azure allows a 256k message. Has anyone else noticed this issue?

Comment: Have you tried another Azure IoT Library as discussed over here? :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/476742/azure-iot-message-too-big.html

Comment: When you say, _The TCP buffer setting does allow larger messages_, do you mean the message is sent to IoT Hub in a single message or in different size chunks? Have you tried any other protocols or devices?

Answer (score 1):

The following [document section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#iot-hub-limits) lists the limits associated with the different service tiers S1, S2, S3, and F1. Device-to-cloud messages can be at most 256 KB, and can be grouped in batches to optimize sends. Batches can be at most 256 KB.

I would suggest making use of a different Azure IoT Library or a different device which you can repro the same issue or maybe with another protocol?

[Throttling details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#throttling-details)

[image]

IoT Hub measures [message size in a protocol-agnostic way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct#message-size), considering only the actual payload. The size in bytes is calculated as the sum of the following values:

- The body size in bytes.
- The size in bytes of all the values of the message system properties.
- The size in bytes of all user property

  names and values.

[device-to-cloud messages can be at most 256 KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5002324)

*The total message size, including the enrichments, can't exceed 256 KB. If a message size exceeds 256 KB, the IoT Hub will drop the message. You can use IoT Hub metrics to identify and debug errors when messages are dropped. For example, you can monitor the telemetry messages incompatible (d2c.telemetry.egress.invalid) metric in the routing metrics. To learn more, see Monitor IoT Hub.*